# How to use these Gmail shortcuts (Cmd+. and Cmd+,)

Tags: mac, gmail

Where is the cursor supposed to be before hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+ <kbd>,</kbd> to make them work?

Do I have to press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> ?

I tried it with and without hitting the Shift key with the cursor in the mail body. Then with the cursor in the main window.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that you have the setting enabled through your Gmail settings. Go into your gmail settings via the [image: Settings] icon and turn on the option.

Once you have keyboard shortcuts enabled you should be able to hit a specific key on your keyboard to execute certain commands. For example, if I want to compose a new message I would hit the <kbd>c</kbd> key. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> would open that option in a new window. For most of the other commands you can hit the corresponding key on the keyboard.

[Gmail keyboard shortcuts.](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en)

Comment: Yassar Thanks for your answer. I think I've found the answer to my question ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered this shortcut on a cheat sheet in French. Now that I have set my Gmail default language in English I understand how to make it work.

If some Frenchies are interested:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> helps you move the focus from one chat window the next chat window.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> helps you move the focus from one chat window to the previous chat window.

Thanks Google for your cheat sheet.

Comment: You should specify the shortcut to help other people.

Comment: Just updated my answer.